# open a new version with the same package name android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, backup, versioning

I would like to add code to my app but I would like to do that on a new version in case so that i can always get back to my older version which worked. 
I need the package name to be the same cause i'm using  google services like :JSON and firebase which are relies on the package name.

Could someone please advise step by step?

when I tried to open a new project and copy the files to that new project got warnings like INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK and Gridle not imported. for example:

"Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_slice_2_apk was defined multiple times.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?"

Comment: what about code versioning ? git for instance

Comment: You should use a version control, Github or Bitbucket for example. Keep the Working code under the name of Stable branch and whenever you are working on any new implementation or feature make a new branch and continue your development. This way you will always have a working copy of last stable code.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Helped me a lot